# Generic method to return function returning generic self-type without the need to cast

Tags: java, generics, self-type

Honestly, I'm not even sure whether that title makes sense. Hopefully the code following will explain the issue at hand.

```java
package what.ever.you.like;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

class SelfTypeTemplates {

    public static <SELF extends AbstractSelfType> UnaryOperator<SELF> simpleBound() {
        return self -> self;
    }

    public static <SELF extends AbstractSelfType<SELF>> UnaryOperator<SELF> boundWithGenericType() {
        return self -> self;
    }
}

class ConcreteSelfType extends AbstractSelfType<ConcreteSelfType> {

    public ConcreteSelfType() {
        super(ConcreteSelfType.class);
    }

    public ConcreteSelfType applySimpleBound() {
        // How to get rid of the type cast?
        return (ConcreteSelfType) SelfTypeTemplates.simpleBound().apply(this);
    }

    public ConcreteSelfType applyBoundWithGenericType() {
        // Compile error because `this` is ConcreteSelfType, but required is SELF
        return SelfTypeTemplates.boundWithGenericType().apply(this);
    }
}

class AbstractSelfType<SELF extends AbstractSelfType<SELF>> {
    protected final SELF myself;

    protected AbstractSelfType(final Class<?> type) {
        this.myself = (SELF) type.cast(this);
    }
}
```

My issue is with the two methods `applySimpleBound()` and `applyBoundWithGenericType()`.
The former is compiling fine, but needs explicit casting, which is what I'd like to get rid of.
The later does not compile, because `.apply(this)` requires a type `SELF` but provided is `ConcreteSelfType`.

So my question is, how do I specify the signature of a method in `SelfTypeTemplates` to return an `UnaryOperator<SELF>` so that invoking the returned function (`.apply(this)`), does **not need casting** in the client code (i.e. `ContreteSelfType`)?

Tried to play with different bounds in the generic and return type. Haven't found a working version without type casting.

Comment: What is this SelfTypeTemplates? Can you share the code for this?

Comment: It's the first class in the example given. The class is fictional. Basically it's supposed to be the API of which I want to figure out the signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the compiler cannot infer the correct type for what ever reason. To work around this issue you can specify it like this:

```
class ConcreteSelfType extends AbstractSelfType<ConcreteSelfType> {

    public ConcreteSelfType() {
        super(ConcreteSelfType.class);
    }

    public ConcreteSelfType applySimpleBound() {
        // How to get rid of the type cast?
        return SelfTypeTemplates.<ConcreteSelfType>simpleBound().apply(this);
    }

    public ConcreteSelfType applyBoundWithGenericType() {
        // Compile error because `this` is ConcreteSelfType, but required is SELF
        return SelfTypeTemplates.<ConcreteSelfType>boundWithGenericType().apply(this);
    }
}
```

Both options compile this way and you don't need a cast.

Comment: The reason why the compiler cannot infer the type in this case, is that the actual type is not given when the generic method is called - only afterwards with the `apply`. Type inference unfortunately cannot resolve the type through chained methods. Your solution is the right answer - it tells the compiler what the type should be.

Comment: Thank you berse2212 for your suggestion! Though, from a syntactical point of view this does not solve my issue, as I still need to specify the type explicitly.
@RobSpoor Ahh ok. Thank you so much for clarifying! To me your comment is the right answer, i.e. "not possible because the type has to be given during the invokation of the generic method".